# Calculating 'minutes' between two two date/time columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know this should be a pretty easy one, but when I read other peoples questions and view answers, I have a hard time understanding how it ties into my existing query. Its just a mental block I think.

Anyway, in SQL Server 2008, I'm looking to display a new column in addition to whats listed already. All data comes from just the one table. My current Start_time & End_time display in (yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss). I just want to create a new column called **Time_To_Complete** after End_time, showing the difference between these two date/time columns, in minutes only.

This is my base query

```
SELECT Index_ID
      ,Start_time
      ,End_time

FROM table_name WITH (NOLOCK)

ORDER BY Start_time DESC
```

Comment: `1440 == datediff(minute, '2014-02-06 12:00:00', '2014-02-07 12:00:00')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Index_ID 
      ,Start_time 
      ,End_time
      ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Start_time,End_time) AS  Time_To_Complete

FROM table_name WITH (NOLOCK)

ORDER BY Start_time DESC
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly, Thx M.Ali

Answer (score 1):

Use [DATEDIFF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx):

```
SELECT Index_ID ,
        Start_time ,
        End_time, 
        Time_To_Complete = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Start_Time, End_Time)
FROM table_name WITH (NOLOCK)
ORDER BY Start_time DESC
```

Or if you want it as a column in the table, add a [computed column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
ADD Time_To_Complete AS DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Start_Time, End_Time)
```